# getActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator() Breaking Navigation Drawer "Hamburger" Animation

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

In my application, I'm using a Navigation Drawer. I have given each item in the Navigation Drawer a different Icon for opening the Nav Drawer.

When I initially start the app, the drawer icon for the first fragment animates like normal. But when I click on another Nav Drawer Item, the animations break.

In my MainActivity, I have this code for toggling the nav drawer:

```
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ab_mytasks, R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
```

Then in each of my fragments, I have this code for setting the custom icon:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ab_mytasks);

}
```

I have tried putting in the same mDrawerToggle method as in my MainActivity into my fragments. But the app crashes when I use getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu().

Here is an image representation of my problem:

```
1 = Animation works as normal
2 = Selected another fragment from Nav Drawer
3 = Original Fragment icon animation is broken
```

[image: 1 = Works as normal, 2=Selected another item, 3=Original Fragment broken]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change the icon (`setHomeAsUpIndicator`) you will no longer get an animation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That would explain it. Is there any way to work around that?

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd include an animation, but you'd have to design your own manually. That particular animation is included in Lollipop but it won't just generate animations when you give it a foreign icon.

Answer (score 0):

Another Answer for this is that the drawer toggle needs to sync again when switching fragments so you have to put `mDrawerToggle.syncState();` in an `onOptionsItemSelected()` method so that each time the navigation changes, fragments the toggle sync up.